# How do I check if a file is text-based?

Tags: file, text, encoding, text-files

I am working on a small text replacement application that basically lets the user select a file and replace text in it without ever having to open the file itself. However, I want to make sure that the function only runs for files that are text-based. I thought I could accomplish this by checking the encoding of the file, but I've found that Notepad .txt files use Unicode UTF-8 encoding, and so do MS Paint .bmp files. Is there an easy way to check this without placing restrictions on the file extensions themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, given the Windows environment that you're working with, I'd consider a whitelist of known text formats. Windows users are typically trained to stick with extensions. However, I would personally relax the requirement that it not function on non-text files, instead checking with the user for goahead if the file does not match the internal whitelist. The risk of changing a binary file would be mitigated if your search string is long - that is assuming you're not performing Y2K conversion (a la `sed 's/y/k/g'`).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you get a huge hint from somewhere, you're stuck. Purely by examining the bytes there's a non-zero probability you'll guess wrong given the plethora of encodings ("ASCII", Unicode, UTF-8, DBCS, MBCS, etc).  Oh, and what if the first page happens to look like ASCII but the next page is a btree node that points to the first page...

Hints can be:

- extension (not likely that foo.exe is editable)
- something in the stream itself (like BOM [byte-order-marker])
- user direction (just edit the file, goshdarnit)

Windows used to provide an API IsTextUnicode that would do a probabilistic examination, but there were well-known false-positives.

My take is that trying to be smarter than the user has some issues...

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty costly to determine if a file is text-based or not (i.e. a binary file). You would have to examine each byte in the file to determine if it is a valid character, irrespective of the file encoding.

Comment: So basically it's not worth the effort, or the performance sacrifice, to implement this? I guess I'll have to use the extension check method after all. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Others have said to look at all the bytes in the file and see if they're alphanumeric.  Some UNIX/Linux utils do this, but just check the first 1K or 2K of the file as an "optimistic optimization".

Answer (score 0):

well a text file contains text, right ? so a really easy way to check a file if it does contain only text is to read it and check if it does contains alphanumeric characters.

So basically the first thing you have to do is to check the file encoding if its pure ASCII you have an easy task just read the whole file in to a char array (I'm assuming you are doing it in C/C++ or similar) and check every char in that array with functions [isalpha](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/isalpha) and [isdigit](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/isdigit) ...of course you have to take care about special exceptions like tabulators '\t' space ' ' or the newline ('\n' in linux , '\r'\'n' in windows)

In case of a different encoding the process is the same except the fact that you have to use different functions for checking if the current character is an alphanumeric character... also note that in case of UTF-16 or greater a simple char array is simply to small...but if you are doing it for example in C# you dont have to worry about the size :)

Comment: Unfortunately, "text" comes in many representations. Text to you and I and many Roman-font-languages can be ASCII. Cyrillic (Russia, Serbia, Bulgaria) isn't there, although some code pages have it in the upper 128 range. Kanji, Han, Hangeul (all far east languages) have glyphs whose numeric representation aren't "alphanumeric", indeed they take more than 8 bits to represent.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that will try to determine if a file is text based. While this will not be 100% accurate, it may be just enough for you. Such a function does not need to go through the whole file, about a kilobyte should be enough (or even less). One thing to do is to count how many whitespaces and newlines are there. Another thing would be to consider individual bytes and check if they are alphanumeric or not. With some experiments you should be able to come up with a decent function. Note that this is just a basic approach and text encodings might complicate things.